# How can I invoke name() inside an interface for an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

I defined an interface for enum types.

```java
interface MyInterface<E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface<E>> {
}

// e.g.
enum MyEnum implements MyInterface<MyEnum> {
}
```

Now I want to access `name()` method from a method defined in above interface.

```java
interface MyInterface<E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface<E>> {

    default void doSomeWithEnumName() {
        // How can I access #name() method in here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `this` to an `Enum<?>` and just access `name()`.

```
System.out.println(((Enum<?>) this).name());
```

**However,** with the current set up, it is in fact possible for one to be naughty and create a non-enum class that implements your interface:

```
enum Bar implements MyInterface<Bar> {}
class Foo implements MyInterface<Bar> {}
```

Therefore, I would advise that you check the type of `this` first:

```
if (this instanceof Enum<?> enumThis) {
    System.out.println(enumThis.name());
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Only enums can implement this interface!");
}
```

(I can't think of how you would limit the interface to be only implementable only for enums - there are no "self" types in Java)